# Is it feasible to measure the pH of solution consisting of hydrofluoric acid, methanol and water using redox potential method?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, redox, analytical-chemistry

Is it feasible to measure the pH of $\ce{HF}:\ce{H3COH}:\ce{H2O}$ solution using redox potential method?

Can I use this method to calculate the $\ce{H+}$ ions in this solution and specifically, can I measure the changes in pH simultaneously as auto ionization is taking place?